# IP encryption using Java

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt my captured IP address in Netbeans Java, but when I run my form I get the message `addr is of illegal length`. Why am I getting that error?

Here's the code:

```
if (packet instanceof IPPacket) {

    IPPacket ipp = (IPPacket) packet;
    InetAddress dest = ipp.dst_ip;
    KeyGenerator keygenerator;

    try {
        keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
        Cipher desCipher;
        // Create the cipher
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
        byte[] ipEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(ipp.dst_ip.getAddress());
        InetAddress src = ipp.src_ip;
        //   System.out.println(dest);
        try {
            ipp.dst_ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipEncrypted);
        } catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        ipp.src_ip = src;
    } catch(Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Your question is answered below, but I have to ask: why are you doing this?

Comment: Its my senior project and i must capture packets and anonymize them..Iam starting by reading ip Packet and encrypte them.

Comment: In that case, you don't necessarily have to encrypt the IP addresses (implying the ability to recover the original address), you only have to choose a function such that `address != f(address)` and `f(address) == f(address)`... say, the leading 4 bytes of your favorite cryptographic hash.

Comment: Tell that to my supervisor..He gave me this task " to encrypte the ip address".

Comment: As others pointed out, it's to do with how many bytes DES requires. For IPv4, you could append or prepend 4 bytes of all zero. For IPv6, you could split the address into two halves. That gives you blocks of the required size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because DES outputs 8-byte blocks, while IPv4 and IPv6 addresses require 4 bytes or 16 bytes, respectively.

Comment: @AnthonyG.Helou You should only create `InetAddress` instances with valid addresses. Your code is trying to use random byte sequences. Even if they were the correct length, what possible use would such an address have?

Comment: can you show me how to create Inetaddress instances with valid Addresses? thank you

Comment: If you are anonymizing the record, by definition you are destroying the address information. You are essentially replacing the address with an identifier that can be used to group records, but not be used as an address or associated with the original address. If you need an address, use the unencrypted original. If you are trying to anonymize the records, encrypt the address and erase the key you used, using the encrypted result only as an identifier. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

public static InetAddress getByAddress(byte[] addr)
                                throws UnknownHostException
Returns an InetAddress object given the raw IP address . The argument is in network byte order: the highest order byte of the address is in getAddress()[0].
This method doesn't block, i.e. no reverse name service lookup is performed.

IPv4 address byte array must be 4 bytes long and IPv6 byte array must be 16 bytes long

I believe for DES the block size is 8 bytes .. so the output from encryption would be in sizes of multiples of 8. you can probably confirm this by checking the length of ipEncrypted.

Comment: if you really want to encrypt IP adresses properly write a custom DES implementation. its pretty straight forward. this link will explain the entire process. you can modify it to encrypt the correct size of inputs. As mentioned above i cant think of why anyone would want to lookup an encrypted ip address but  since you asked ....http://n3vrax.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/des-algorithm-java-implementation/